# issue with serving static files with socket.io

Tags: jquery, node.js, express, socket.io

I'm creating a web application where a user can login (pwd/username). Once logged in, he can choose one of 2 available apps.
The first app, uses http connection between the client and the server.
The second one uses web socket. So when the user clicks on the second app, a websocket should be established.
My first app works fine, also the second one, but when I put all together. I have a problem.

Here is what I have done so far:

### server.js

```
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app, function(req, res) {
  //serves static files
  //processes GET and POST requests of both the login page and the 1st app 
}

server.listen(80, function() {
   console.log("Server listening on port 80.");
}); 

app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.cookieParser());
    app.use(express.session({secret: 'secret', key: 'express.sid'}));
});

 app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   var filePath = '../client/index.html';
   if (filePath){
      var absPath = './' + filePath;
      serveStatic(res, cache, absPath); //function that serves static files
   } 
}); 
io = io.listen(server);
io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
  //code
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
  console.log('Client connected.');
});
```

### index.html

```
    <script src="../third-party/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

    tick = io.connect();
          tick.on('data', function (data) {
              console.log(data);
          });

          tick.on('error', function (reason){
            console.error('Unable to connect Socket.IO', reason);
          });

          tick.on('connect', function (){
            console.info('successfully established a working and authorized connection');
          });
    });
</script>
```

On the client side, I use jquery.

When I connect to my localhost, I get the login page, and an error message on chrome debugger tool saying that: $ is undefined (in index.html), `GET http://localhost/third-party/jquery-1.9.1.min.js 404 (Not Found)`

Here is the architecture of my app:

```
- server
   - server.js
-client
     -index.html (login page)
     -firstApp 
       -index.html
     -secondApp (uses websocket)   
         -index.html
     - third-party
         -jquery-1.9.1.min.js
```

I believe, I'm not serving static files in the right way. Although, before adding the websocket to my code, I didn't have any problem with that.
What I don't understand is when I log something under

```
var server = http.createServer(app, function(req, res) {
   console.log('TEST')
});
```

nothing is shown on the console.
Here is how the function that serves static files:

```
function sendFile(res, filePath, fileContents) {
   res.writeHead(200, {"content-type": mime.lookup(path.basename(filePath))});
   res.end(fileContents);
} 

function serveStatic(res, cache, absPath) {
   //checks if file is cached in memory
   if (cache[absPath]) {
      sendFile(res, absPath, cache[absPath]); //serves file from memory
   }else {
      fs.exists(absPath, function(exists) { //checks if file exists
         if (exists) { 
            fs.readFile(absPath, function(err, data) { //reads file from disk
               if (err) {
               }else {
                  cache[absPath] = data;
                  sendFile(res, absPath, data); //serves file from disk
               }
            });
         }else {
            console.log('cannot find the file')
            send404(res);
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Just add

`app.use( express.static(__dirname+'../client') );`

to your middleware chain, and request files from your `index.html` relativelly to the client directory, as follows:

**secondApp/index.html**

```html
<script src="/third-party/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

`express.static` is a reference to [connect.static](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/static.html)

### IMHO, please cleanup your server.js code at least to

```js
var app = express()
  , server = http.createServer(app)
  , io = io.listen(server)
;

app.configure(function () {
    app.use( express.cookieParser() );
    app.use( express.session({secret: 'secret', key: 'express.sid'}) );
    app.use( app.router )
    app.use( express.static(__dirname+'../client') );
});


app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile( __dirname+'../client/index.html' ) 
});

app.get('/whatever/url/path/you/want', function (req, res) {
    // this will match GET requests to /whatever/url/path/you/want
});

app.get('*', function (req, res) {
    // this will match GET requests to any path
    // take care if you use middlewares after app.router as here
});

app.post('/whatever/url/path/you/want', function (req, res) {
    // this will match POST requests to /whatever/url/path/you/want
});

app.post('*', function (req, res) {
    // this will match POST requests to any path
});

io.set('authorization', function (handshakeData, accept) {
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) { 
  console.log('Client connected.');
});

server.listen(80, function() {
   console.log("Server listening on port 80.");
});
```

#### WARNING: The above is not the cleanest neither best code written ever

### Take a look at the [http.createServer documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_createserver_requestlistener)

It does only accept 1 listener for resquest. You could register 2 listeners, but since you are using express the best way is to use its features, see the examples above on the server.js example code

### You don't need those `serveStatic` function you mention

`express.static` will be enough for you.

## Side note

You don't need to wrap `io.connect` under `$.ready` on the client side

Comment: Thank you for your answer.But I still have a problem of the undefined $ . You suggested to clean up the code by removing the callback function in createServer but there is where I serve the static files. If I need to server third-party/jquery.js, the req.url in app.get() should log third-party/jquery.js, that is not the case here. You can see the comment I left under Paul Harris answer

Comment: @user1499220 you don't need the extra callback function in createServer. With changes suggested, you have to simply update the urls of the scripts on the index.html files. I've edited my answer, please take a look at

Comment: Thank you again for your answer. I did like you suggested but I still have the same error. Also,the firstApp/index.html and index.html don't use socket.io, why do I need to include socket.io source? Regarding http.createServer, I need the callback function to process the POST and GET requests received from the firstApp and from the login page. If I remove this callback, where shall I process these requests?

Comment: @user1499220 ok, I added some examples about POST and GET routing with express. You should research a bit about express. I see you ask basic questions that when known the answers will lead you to succeed on your targets. Please follow to [express api docs](http://expressjs.com/api.html), specially [the routing section](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.VERB)